# Load PHP in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I've got some PHP code where it says the time you signed up, and gives an approximation of how long ago it was.
I've been looking into trying to refresh it with javascript, but I'm struggling to find exactly what I'm after, and as my knowledge of it isn't good I'm a bit stuck on getting it working now.

Basically, this is the code I currently have, with the function being the thing displaying the time since singing up

```
Date registered:  <?PHP echo date('jS F Y', $_SESSION['User_Date'])." at ".date('G:i:s', $_SESSION['User_Date']);
        echo " (".time_delta('now',date('F j Y G:i:s', $_SESSION['User_Date'])).")"; ?>
```

Which will output something like:
Date registered: 4th November 2013 at 0:57:31 (About 34 minutes ago)

And I've got this for javascript, but I don't know how to make it just update the text and not redirect the page.

```
 <script>
    setInterval(function() {
    window.location.href = "timeupdate.php";
    }, 1000);
 </script>
```

Would there be a simple way to do this, or is it worth avoiding it in terms of cpu usage?

Comment: Take a look at Ajax - it'll let you query `timeupdate.php` in the background, and then update the page with the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have suggested AJAX is your answer.

With [jQuery an ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
       $.ajax({
           url: "timeupdate.php",
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "html",
           success: function(html) {
           $("#date_registered_element").html(html);
        }
      });//end ajax call
    },1000);//end setInterval
});//end docReady
```

This will output the text returned from timeupdate.php to a div with the id of "date_registered_element" -> change this to the name of the div to which you wish to output the updated text.

In order to pass a session variable to the Ajax function you need to have the server echo out the Session variable before the script runs (i.e. as the page is rendered) something like this: 
HTML:

```
<div id="user_date" style="display: none;">
    <?php echo $_SESSION["User_Date"]; ?>
</div>
```

**Please NOTE:** You need to be very careful with this. Anyone who looks at your markup in a browsers View Source or Developer Tools will be able to see the SESSION Variable echod out. You should only do this if the data represents no security risk. In my opinion you would be better passing no GET variables in the Ajax call and just referencing the SESSION variable in the timeupdate.php script. The point of SESSION variables is to provide state-like functionality to HTTP so you should never need to send SESSION variables over a HTTP request.

That said, if you wish to do it the way you currently have it set up then the code is below.

Once you have echoed out the SESSION variable onto the page, you can then collect the value from the id with jQuery and pass it to the Ajax function:

Javascript/jQuery:

```
var url = "timeupdate.php?time=" + $("#user_date").text();

//pass the url to the Ajax function in the ajax function like this:
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    //the rest of your ajax function here
});
```

if you  add jQuery to your page `<head></head>` tag **BEFORE** your existing script this should work:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: Ah thanks a lot man, works pretty much perfectly, I've made it lower the update speed at higher times too :)
There is one problem though, it doesn't read anything from the page it's used on. I've managed to pass the time through the url and copied the function onto the script page to get around the problem, but surely there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: This is how I've used your code - http://pastebin.com/HUa95b89, and this is timeupdate.php - http://pastebin.com/qwVVfmmf. The only bit I actually need is the final line, the rest could be removed if I could link it to the rest of the site :P This is what it should be if it was working correctly - http://pastebin.com/LE2QVFJc

Comment: Ok so this: timeupdate.php?time=<?PHP echo $_SESSION['User_Date'] ?> wont work. Javascript is client-side therefore the server that has the session date has no access to the Session variables as they are on the server. If you want to get the User_Date Session variable you will need to echo it out onto the page into a <div> with display:none; and tell jQuery to collect it from there. I will post example code in my edited answer as there is not enough space here

Comment: Answer updated. In short, it would be good for you to read up on client vs server-side techs. Theres some simple and accurate descriptions in the beginning of the Head First books by O'Reilly - try head first jQuery or Head First PHP and MySQL. It sounds like you already know alot of what the books will teach you but they each  have a section on the different between client and server side technologies that will clear some of this up for you.

Comment: Ah ok cheers man :)  The part you mentioned did work alright, as it was still within the main page, and would run before the javascript started. I've not really used php in years with doing vfx at uni, but I know enough of client/server side stuff to know I don't want to be doing anything like writing the password code in javascript or anything haha. This is only the signed up time anyway, it does factor into the password hash, but pretty much everything else does too (including last login time so it changes the stored value each login) so I think it's pretty safe :)